# AES 128 encryption in PHP using PKCS5p adding

Tags: java, php, encryption, aes

I have been trying to encrypt string using AES-128 CBC which was originally crypted using JAVA AES encryption. In java PKCS5 padding is used. And i have tried to encrypt using similar PHP code. But i am getting different result. I think I am getting wrong somewhere in IV parameter value. Can anyone help me on this.

JAVA Code

```
package com.idbi.ib.util;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import sun.misc.BASE64Decoder;
import sun.misc.BASE64Encoder;

public class AESEncryptionDecryptionAlg
{
    public AESEncryptionDecryptionAlg()
    {
    }

    public static String Encrypt(String text, String key) throws Exception {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        byte[] keyBytes= new byte[16];
        byte[] b= key.getBytes("UTF-8");
        int len= b.length;
        if (len > keyBytes.length) len = keyBytes.length;
        System.arraycopy(b, 0, keyBytes, 0, len);
        SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");
        IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(keyBytes);
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE,keySpec,ivSpec);
        byte[] results = cipher.doFinal(text.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        BASE64Encoder encoder = new BASE64Encoder();
        return encoder.encode(results);
    }
}
```

And the equivalent PHP code.

```
function mc_encrypt($plaintext,$key) {
    $iv = $key;
    //For PKCS5 padding
    $block = mcrypt_get_block_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);
    $padding = $block - (strlen($plaintext) % $block);
    $plaintext .= str_repeat(chr($padding), $padding);

    $crypttext = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $plaintext, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);

    $crypttext64 = base64_encode($crypttext);
    $plaintext = $crypttext64;
    return $plaintext;
}
```

Comment: Looks fine (apart from the security problems). Perhaps this has something to do with your key encoding. Can you give an example key and outputs from both snippets?

Comment: Looks fine? They're not passing an IV to `mcrypt_encrypt()`. They're using the key for an IV in their C# code. The two operations are not congruent.

Comment: @Scott Arciszewski. I did applied IV value in mcrypt_encrypt()  but still in getting the value generated by Java code

Comment: JAVA use IV `IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(keyBytes);`, But no specific iv in your PHP